# Is it possible for an impact event to render the Earth's surface unrecognizable while still forming a large complex crater?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, geology

Is it physically possible for a complex crater to form and remain stable after an impact event large enough to deform the Earth's crust globally, insofar that the surface of the planet becomes unrecognizable to an observer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking conflicting requirements.

> the surface of the planet becomes unrecognizable to an observer

means that whatever feature is present on the surface is deeply altered or even destroyed.

Thus

> a complex crater to form and remain stable

cannot happen

Comment: My thinking was that the region impacted would be rendered unrecognizable due to the impact, with the crater forming concurrently to the surrounding destruction. But my understanding of impact event timelines could be as flawed as my wording.